# How can I retrieve a full list of companies (advertisers) from the Google Ad Manager API?

Tags: google-api, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I'm building a rails 5 API that interacts with Google Ad Manager API and I need a way to retrieve the list of companies (also called advertisers) so I can use them in order to create new orders and eventually, line items.

I haven't been able to find this in the Ad Manager documentation, not for ruby and not for other languages either.

I don't have any code yet since I don't know what service to use.

I'd expect an array of advertisers: [{:name => 'Company 1', :id => '1234'}, {:name => 'Company 2', :id => '4321'}]

Any help would be really appreciated. I haven't been able to find this in the Ad Manager documentation, not for ruby and not for other languages either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I was wrong, it is part of the Ruby examples:

```
def get_advertisers(ad_manager)
  company_service = ad_manager.service(:CompanyService, API_VERSION)

  # Create a statement to select companies.
  statement = ad_manager.new_statement_builder do |sb|
    sb.where = 'type = :type'
    sb.with_bind_variable('type', 'ADVERTISER')
  end

  # Retrieve a small amount of companies at a time, paging
  # through until all companies have been retrieved.
  page = {:total_result_set_size => 0}
  begin
    # Get the companies by statement.
    page = company_service.get_companies_by_statement(
        statement.to_statement()
    )

    # Print out some information for each company.
    unless page[:results].nil?
      page[:results].each_with_index do |company, index|
        puts '%d) Company with ID %d, name "%s", and type "%s" was found.' %
            [index + statement.offset, company[:id], company[:name],
            company[:type]]
      end
    end

    # Increase the statement offset by the page size to get the next page.
    statement.offset += statement.limit
  end while statement.offset < page[:total_result_set_size]

  puts 'Total number of companies: %d' % page[:total_result_set_size]
end
```